# How to add backticks to elements of a string in Jenkins Groovy?

Tags: string, character, jenkins-groovy

I have a variable in groovy which is a string of the following:

`Computers = home,laptop,garage`

I want to reformat this so every element of the string has backticks around it like so:

```
Computers = `home`,`laptop`,`garage`
```

I am looking for a solution that works for any number of these elements, e.g. if we have:

`Computers = home,laptop,garage,basement,attic`

It should transform them to:

```
Computers = `home`,`laptop`,`garage`,`basement`,`attic`
```

How can I achieve this in Jenkins Groovy?

I tried doing

```
Computers = "`" + Computers = "`"
```

But that only adds them to the beginning and end of the whole string.